# Find the record which have the greater value in top 2 month

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to retrieve a record where the age group is greater than 50 and show the top 2 month.

```
So, this is my table with 3 column 

Age_group infection Month 
30-39     50        2
40-49     11        1
40-49     18        4
50-59     27        2
60-69     30        4
50-59     5         3
70-79     23        3
50-59     4         1 

The result should return like this: 

Month 
4 
3
```

As we can see in the age_group there is 2 row fall in month ‘3’. The total value in month ‘3’ is 28. And the another month which have the greater value is month ‘4’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `group by month` and sum the infections before you sort and return the top2:

```
select month, sum(infection) total_infection
from tablename
where age_group > '50'
group by month
order by total_infection desc
limit 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wfoeUaNs5ngUm5tkMaKvfK/0).
Results:

```
| Month | total_infection |
| ----- | --------------- |
| 4     | 30              |
| 3     | 28              |
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where age_group >= '50'
order by infection desc
limit 2;
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to use direct string comparisons in the `WHERE` clause, but I guess what you have should actually work +1.

Comment: Using Order by infection desc but how you know the total infection base on month. Because in month 3 there is 2 record. Limit 2 is just showing the top 2 row.

Comment: You need to order by month and then by infection @FufuAlex.

Answer (score 0):

Based on requirements, it seems you first want to order by month desc and then by infection count and hence this should be the correct query:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where age_group >= '50'
order by month desc, infection desc
limit 2;
```